# Invalid array length when trying to create an array from calculation

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

```
var map = {
    mapSize: 100, // the size of a side
    data: new Array(this.mapSize * this.mapSize),

    getIndex: function(x, y) {
        return x * this.mapSize + y;
    },

    getCoords: function(index) {
        var x = Math.floor(index/this.mapSize);
        return {
            x: x,
            y: index - (x * this.mapSize)
        }
    }
};
```

This code gives me RangeError: Invalid array length.
However when there is no calculation, like this:

```
data: new Array(this.mapSize),
```

it works.

Could you explain me why is that happening?

Comment: `this` is not what you think, but you don't need to give your array a length, `data: []`

Comment: `this` in the context of the `data` property is not the object, but probably the window.

Comment: In addition to @elclanrs comment here is an article on why you don't need to use `new Array()` https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w/why-never-use-new-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is that happening

Because `map` object is not yet constructed by the time you are trying to read its `mapSize` property. So `this.mapSize` gives you `undefined`. As the result `undefined * unedefined` produces `NaN`. And Array can't be created with `NaN` length. Try just `new Array(NaN)` and you will see the same error.

Comment: Thanks! I've struggled so much and it was so simple. I've just put this variable before object.

Comment: In addition: to fix the issue maybe declare mapSize outside of the map object like: `var mapSize = 100, map = {mapSize: mapSize, data:[], ... }`